# android studio doesn't let me try different alias when building signed apk

Tags: android-studio, alias, keystore

I tried to build a signed apk but i wrote an incorrect alias and build failed, now whenever i try to build writing the correct alias and passwords build still fails but the error messagge is:
No key with alias 'old alias' found in keystore 
Can someone explain me how do I build with a different alias name?
My keystore and alias passwords are 100% correct.

Comment: if your app not yet published, then may be you can create fresh keystore.

Comment: i have already published... i tried to create a differet certificate anyway but i still have this problem. luckily i cuold use my laptop where i didn't have this bug

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit old but what worked for me was cleaning the project (in Android Studio, go to option "Build" then "Clean project". It may vary depending on your Android Studio version) and then trying again to generate a signed APK with the right alias.